# Session variable content not updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, datagrid, datatable

Consider the code below:

```
\DataTable dt =(DataTable) Session["dfdtemptable"];
    // Remove all
            int i = dt.Rows.Count;
        while(i> 0)
        {
        dt.Rows[i-1].Delete();
        dt.Rows[i - 1].AcceptChanges();
        i--;
        }
        Session["dfdtemptable"] = dt;
        this.BindItems();
```

When the addnew button is clicked the above code is executed. But the Session variable still contains the old values the variable is not cleared..But need to clear the session variable so that there no values in Session.

Comment: Is "dt" cleared after the while?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code It can be happened. B'cos **when i < = 0 same value will exist as earlier**.
B'cos your **Session is in outer loop**.Check that.

```
 while(i> 0)
    {
    dt.Rows[i-1].Delete();
    dt.Rows[i - 1].AcceptChanges();
    i--;
    }
    Session["dfdtemptable"] = dt;
```

Check your `Session["dfdtemptable"];` assigned place(**origin - Not showed for us** - b'cos that **can be generated 0 for i**).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to loop through if all you need is delete all rows. Try this

```
DataTable dt =(DataTable) Session["dfdtemptable"];
dt.Clear();

Session["dfdtemptable"] = dt;
```